# IntelliJ - AutoCompletion not working for new package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am testing a few Java API, I've created my project called 'MyLearning' where all my src files are located, in src I created another Package callede 'myfiles', now when I import the `java.nio.file.Files` API, IntelliJ doesn't show me suggestions for this class. But in the main package i.e `src` folder, the suggestion works totally fine.

Example:
[image]

The above picture shows my main src folder, where the `Files` API works totally fine.

[image]

But then in the new Package that I've created i.e myfiles, it is showing error on retrieving the methods of Files API. Error is

> Cannot resolve symbol 'exists'

Can anyone tell me what could be the poblem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put method calls inside a method.

```
public void foo()
{
    Files.exists(path);
}
```

I also noticed that one of the tags you put is `intellij-14`. The latest version of IntelliJ is `2016.2`.

Comment: If I use this statement It wouldn't work, while it should?

`if(Files.exists(path)){
        //do something
    }`

Comment: The thing is IntelliJ should show me suggestion If I Press [CTRL] + [SPACE] after Files.

Comment: As I've said, you need to put your code inside a method. It isn't IntelliJ's bug, but your code. Your code does not compile if you call methods directly inside a class. IntelliJ has highlighted your code which clearly indicates that there is something wrong. `[ALT] + [ENTER]` should fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call it in a method, not in the class

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Path path = Paths.get("C:\\log.txt");
        System.out.println(Files.exists(path));
    }
}
```

[image]